# ImportError: No module named copy_reg

Tags: python, flask

I am cloning a flask project from github account.That project using python with version of 2.7.14.

I create an environment with python 2.7 and the run the project in flask it shows error as "ImportError: No module named copy_reg".

And in my friend system it shows another error as "ImportError: No module named multiplearray".

Comment: Please add more context to your question. It is very difficult to answer without knowing, for example, the directory in which you're running the python module.

Comment: That's weird, because copy_reg is a stdlib. Could please post the output of: `python --version`?

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python 2.7.15? It's just the copy_reg module was renamed in Python 3 so if you happened to be using Python 3 instead that might be why it isn't imported.

Comment: I created an environment with python 2.7.14 , why because the project version is python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

copy_reg could have been renamed in python 2.7, try this:

```
try:
    import copy_reg
except ImportError:
    import copyreg as copy_reg
```